# Freezing issue when trying to run Linux on chromebook with crouton

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, freeze, chromebook

I'm a total noob but I am trying to install and run Linux so I that I can learn it.

All I have is a chromebook, so I used the method of using crouton to run them at the same time.

I have very limited knowledge on this but I have managed to get to the point where I've installed Linux and when I switch over from chromeOS I keep getting a frozen screen. I can see the Ubuntu linux desktop environment but I can't click on anything - the screen is just frozen. I am, however, able to switch back to chrome and then it works fine. I followed this guide to install:

https://itsfoss.com/install-linux-chromebook/

I'm a beginner here, just trying to get started with Linux with the limited resources that I have. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using your Chromebook's trackpad, tap to click won't work until it's turned on in the Linux settings (usually a gear icon).  Until then you need to press down on the trackpad to make a click.  Hope this is what's going on.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the problem either. I have now tried three times and the same thing happens each time. ChromeOS works just fine, but when I switch over to linux I can see the desktop but not do anything except move the cursor

Comment: Which model Chromebook is this?

Comment: HP CHROMEBOOK 14-DB0023DX

Comment: This is a new model.  Does it not support native Linux?  You would see the option in Settings. This would let you run apps and get a command line which is the main thing you need to learn about Linux anyway.